# Cannot set jsflags in Delphi tchromium DCEF 3 component

Tags: javascript, delphi, tchromium

I am using the Delphi XE5 TChromium component that ship with the DCEF 3 library. It works fine except when I am trying to load a url that makes extensive use of the javascript library. If I load the project in Chrome I can overcome the problem by setting the javascript flags to:

```
 --js-flags="--stack-size 2048"
```

How can I set the same flag for the TChromium component?

thank you for your help

Comment: For the first glance: 1) DCEF as i know is obsolete (it does not supports latest CEF3 builds). Here is more modern package:[WACEF](https://bitbucket.org/WaspAce/wacef) 2) Search for "CommandLine" text in the sources for more info. Sorry, I using CEF3 in my project but have not encountered such problems, so I can only give you approximate way for searching.

Comment: Hi Abelisto, thank you for your suggestion. I have installed the TWAChromium component, dropped one instance on a form but when I try to run the project an error message appear saying: "Exception EOSError in module Project1.exe at 00028B47. System Error. Code 126. The specified module could not be found.". Any suggestion? Sorry for bothering you further...

Comment: For DCEF3: See module ceflib.pas, function CefLoadLib, parameter JavaScriptFlags.

Comment: Set value for the variable CefJavaScriptFlags when your app starts.